# How do I convert a IEnumerable<SubClass> to IEnumerable<ParentClass>

Tags: .net, collections, ienumerable

How do I go from (cast?, convert?):

```
IEnumerable<Square>
```

to

```
IEnumerable<Shape>
```

Comment: Which version of .NET is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using anything lower than .NET 4.0, then you're going to have to use [IEnumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Square> squares = new List<Square>();

// Fill the collection

IEnumerable<Shape> shapes = squares.Cast<Shape>();
```

.NET 4.0 introduces new Covariance and Contravariance features that allow you to make that cast directly:

```
IEnumerable<Square> squares = new List<Square>();
IEnumerable<Shape> shapes = (IEnumerable<Shape>)squares;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var shapes = squares.Cast<Shape>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you don't have to.

From [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) (emphasis added):

> Polymorphism enables you to assign an instance of Derived to a variable of type Base. Similarly, because the type parameter of the IEnumerable(T) interface is covariant, **you can assign an instance of `IEnumerable<Derived>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Base>`**...

Since you're asking this question, I assume you're not using .NET 4.0 yet. But this might be a reason to upgrade, if you're able to.